# Facebook can't access my web app image

Tags: image, facebook, share

i try to share a link from the web app which i am making.

But facebook can't access my web app's image .

is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: How about sharing some code! providing some links....

Comment: I meant edit the question and share the code that is causing the problem with us...also try providing some links to check them online for you!

Comment: i am working for a client project , where the idea[web app] was new and more confidentially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't provide much information, these are some tips:
Use the full list of [Open Graph Meta Tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like):

- og:title - The title of the entity.
- og:type - The type of entity. You must select a type from the list of Open Graph types.
- og:image - The URL to an image that represents the entity. Images must be at least 50 pixels by 50 pixels. Square images work best, but you are allowed to use images up to three times as wide as they are tall.
- og:url - The canonical, permanent URL of the page representing the entity. When you use Open Graph tags, the Like button posts a link to the og:url instead of the URL in the Like button code.
- og:site_name - A human-readable name for your site, e.g., "IMDb".
- fb:admins or fb:app_id - A comma-separated list of either the Facebook IDs of page administrators or a Facebook Platform application ID. At a minimum, include only your own Facebook ID.

After adding the Meta Tags, run the website again in the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to clear the Facebook caching.