# sharing a link on facebook: how to get thumbnails?

Tags: facebook

I've put in my page's header the following

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://fractalsoft.s3.amazonaws.com/sfondo.jp2" />
```

but the thumb is not showing up.

I think the problem is that the image is located outside the site.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook can't access my web app image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291462/facebook-cant-access-my-web-app-image)

Comment: Also that's not an actual image url (http://fractalsoft.s3.amazonaws.com/sfondo.jp2). it's resolving as an access denied response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i just added this inside my  tag and i was done:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://s3.amazonaws.com/andrea/photos/activities/26/medium.jpg?1304082168"/>
```

And there are other useful tags:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="..."/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="..."/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="activity"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="..."/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="..."/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="..."/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="..."/>
```

Hope this helps!